# Subdomain Mapping to AWS server

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain

We have domain name registration with GoDaddy and website has been hosted with Bigrock and the name servers have been updated accordingly. Now we are hosting an application in AWS and we intend to create a subdomain and direct to to AWS while retaining the pimary site as is in Bigrock. Please suggest best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You would create either a A record (IPv4 IP address), AAAA (IPv6 IP Address) or CNAME (another domain) of `subdomain.example.com` and set it to the value of your AWS resource.